# Strange Exception, What is it saying?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
    System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'SportSoft.SSBLL.CMembershipTypeAdvanceBooking' to type 'SportSoft.SSBLL.CAreaActivities'.
  Source=SSDlgs
  StackTrace:
       at SportSoft.SSDlgs.frmAdvanced.ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\a_rahnema\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SSDlgs\Booking\frmAdvanced.vb:line 56
       at System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at SportSoft.SSBLL.CBOView.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\a_rahnema\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SSBLL\BOView.vb:line 200
       at SportSoft.SSBLL.CBOView.AddNew() in C:\Documents and Settings\a_rahnema\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SSBLL\BOView.vb:line 680
       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.AddNew()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.AddNewRow()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridAddNewRow.OnEdit()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.Edit(String displayText)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.OnEnter(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.NotifyEnter()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.UpdateFocusedControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.AssignActiveControlInternal(Control value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ActivateControlInternal(Control control, Boolean originator)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ActivateControlInternal(Control control)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmSetFocus(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SetFocus(HandleRef hWnd)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.FocusInternal()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at SportSoft.ssBOffice.frmMain.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\a_rahnema\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ssBOffice\Forms\frmMain.vb:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: "Unable to cast object of type 'SportSoft.SSBLL.CMembershipTypeAdvanceBooking' to type 'SportSoft.SSBLL.CAreaActivities'." What are CMembershipTypeAdvanceBooking and CAreaActivities types?

Comment: NOOOOOO! MFC-style naming! The beast is not dead yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `frmAdvanced` class, you have a `ListChangedEventHandler`.  Somewhere within this method, you're trying to cast a  `SportSoft.SSBLL.CMembershipTypeAdvanceBooking` to type `SportSoft.SSBLL.CAreaActivities`.  This is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's saying that it can't cast an object of type `SportSoft.SSBLL.CMembershipTypeAdvanceBooking` to type `SportSoft.SSBLL.CAreaActivities` on line 56 of `frmAdvanced.vb` :)

Answer (score 1):

In the file frmAdvanced.vb on line 56, you are setting a variable of type `CAreaActivities` to value of type `CMembershipTypeAdvanceBooking`.

Since `CMembershipTypeAdvanceBooking` does not inherit from `CAreaActivities` the assignment fails at runtime.

If you would like additional help, you should post a portion the text of frmAdvanced.vb that includes line 56.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying the object being cast cannot be cast to the type specified.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx

Answer (score 0):

its saying:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'SportSoft.SSBLL.CMembershipTypeAdvanceBooking'
>   to type
>   'SportSoft.SSBLL.CAreaActivities'.

somewhere there is code that is trying to make an `CMembershipTypeAdvanceBooking` object into a `CAreaActivities` object and that it is not allowed.